# Uploading and retrieving image file on blob store using python doesent work

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I am very new to Google App engine and was trying to understand bolb storage and api, but cant get it working.

I followed the the below tutorial from goolge on using blobstore api

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/

Github:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-blobstore-python/blob/master/main.py

I always get 404 not found error, the image is getting uploaded to the blob store but is not being retrieved. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the user authentication from user photo class resolved the issue. Also remove it from instantiation line
user = ndb.StringProperty()

Answer (score 0):

This is https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-blobstore-python/issues/3

The tl;dr is that being logged in fixes this.

I've submitted a pull request to fix the example.